# Who is this particular inventor from XIX century?

Tags: 19th-century, inventions, europe

I came acros with the following description about a certain inventor from XIX century:

> An illustrious 19th-century European character who amassed an immense fortune thanks to his more than three hundred inventions, has passed to the annals of history for having developed a device with a photosynthetic organism that was a true economic reef for this inventor. After making a public demonstration of the benefits of this invention in British territory, the German authorities and the Scandinavian countries began to manufacture it, while the British, somewhat more reluctant, would authorize its production several years later. When its use was extended to the industry or public works, among others, the patent made the assets of this character increase substantially.

Additional background: It was also mentioned that this particular substance is related to the inventor:

[image]

We have strong beliefs about [aspirin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirin) but the inventor does not match the description. We also though about [Dynamite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamite) invented by [Alfred Nobel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Nobel).

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: I'm really confused. Can you say where exactly you came across this? Since that appears to be a quotation, it ought to be possible to relate where it was quoted from.

Comment: It's from a quizz in which I can look for information on any source. The one I asked is one of them and I quoted as it was stated on the quizz page.

Comment: Is it possible that the word "reef" in the quote should be "relief"?  And please cite the quote to avoid accusations of plagiarism.  (citations in comments are not correct; the citation should be edited into the question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the correct answer is Alfred Nobel, as you already surmised.

> .... Finally, [Nobel] tried diatomaceous earth, ..., that he brought from the Elbe River near his factory in Hamburg, which successfully stabilized the nitroglycerin into a portable explosive.
>
> Nobel obtained patents for his inventions in England on 7 May 1867

The additional pictorial hint is [diatomaceous earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatomaceous_earth), Nobel's stabilizer for nitroglycerin in inventing and manufacturing dynamite:

> **diatomaceous earth**: ... a naturally occurring, soft, siliceous sedimentary rock that is easily crumbled into a fine white to off-white powder. ....
>
> Diatomaceous earth consists of fossilized remains of diatoms, a type of hard-shelled protist.  It is used as ..., a stabilizing component for dynamite, ....

As for [diatoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diatom):

> Similar to plants, diatoms convert light energy to chemical energy by photosynthesis ....